# Meaning of "Astute logic"?

Tags: meaning

What does "astute logic" mean? What is the difference between "astute logic" and just "logic" itself?

Comment: Without some context, it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: All we can say is that it's better than half-astute logic. Do you have a usage you can give us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather apt usage I found was a synopsis for a [Sherlock Holmes](https://www.harpercollins.co.uk/9780007934423/the-return-of-sherlock-holmes) book

> "Featuring one of Holmes’ greatest adversaries, Charles Augustus Milverton, as well as trademark **astute logic**, forensic science, murder, cryptograms and magic"

The definition of [Astute](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/astute) is

> 1. of keen penetration or discernment; sagacious: 
>      an astute analysis.
> 2. clever; cunning; ingenious; shrewd: 
>      an astute merchandising program; an astute manipulation of facts

So, we put these words together to interpret this word pairing to mean logical deduction that is quick and incisive in nature.  "Normal" logical deduction can be long and methodical in nature.  A good example is the prior named Sherlock who is able to deduce a logical solution to a problem within a few minutes where it might take the police a few days/weeks.